# why my JavaScript appendchild gives me an error when it to create list

Tags: javascript, node.js

im in my first week of java script coding so forgive me if this is simple question but i have been getting this error "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at HTMLButtonElement.incrementCounter ". when I try to add li items in my ul this is the code.

```
const incrementBtn = document.querySelector('#increment')
const decrementBtn = document.querySelector('#decrement')
 const counterEl = document.querySelector('#counter') 

const ulElement = document.querySelector('#list-items')
let counter = 0

function incrementCounter() {
    counter ++
    counterEl.innerText = counter

    // create element 
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const texNode = document.createTextNode('senntence '+ counter)
    // append element 
    ulElement.appendChild('li')
}
function decrementCounter() {
    counter --
    counterEl.innerText = counter
}

incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', incrementCounter)
decrementBtn.addEventListener('click', decrementCounter)
```

the goal is li to be displayed when the increment button is clicked.

ill appreciate the help.
thank you.

Comment: In `ulElement.appendChild('li')`, 'li' is a string, so it will fail. To use the element you just created before, use `ulElement.appendChild(li)`

Answer (score 0):

**You just mistyped your variable as a string**

Here is the fixed code:

```js
const incrementBtn = document.querySelector('#increment')
const decrementBtn = document.querySelector('#decrement')
 const counterEl = document.querySelector('#counter') 

const ulElement = document.querySelector('#list-items')
let counter = 0

function incrementCounter() {
    counter ++
    counterEl.innerText = counter

    // create element 
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const texNode = document.createTextNode('senntence '+ counter)
    // append element 
    ulElement.appendChild(li)
}
function decrementCounter() {
    counter --
    counterEl.innerText = counter
}

incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', incrementCounter)
decrementBtn.addEventListener('click', decrementCounter)
```